# How to save data from phpmyadmin database to pdf?

Tags: php, database, pdf, phpmyadmin

I have a database on phpmyadmin. Then I have a website with some products. When user clicks on a specific product, he gets some details about that product. Those details are pulled from the database.

My question is: Is it possible to create a pdf file with the specific details about that product, so the user can download it?

Comment: There is a library named mPDF that can struct your PDF, generate it and download it with headers, just google it

Comment: Yes, you can use [fpdf library](http://www.fpdf.org/) for that.

Comment: you don't have a phpmyadmin database. You have a mysql database, and are using phpmyadmin to manage/access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the options i know are:

`DOMPDF` : php class that wrap the html and build the pdf. Works good, customizable, based on pdflib, if i remember right it takes even some CSS. Bad news: slow when the html is big or many complex.
this is a tutorial to follow :http://www.sitepoint.com/convert-html-to-pdf-with-dompdf/

`HTML2PS`: same of DOMPDF, but this one convert first in .ps (ghostscript), then, in whatever format you need (pdf, jpg, png). For me is little better then dompdf, but have the same speed problem.. oh, better compatibility with css.

Those two are php classes, but if you can install some software on the server, and access it throught passthru() or system(), give a look to these too:

`wkhtmltopdf`: based on webkit (safari's wrapper), is really fast and powerfull.. seem like is the best one (atm) for convert on the fly html pages to pdf, taking only 2 seconds for a 3 pages xHTML document with CSS2. Is a recent project, anyway, the google.code page is often updated.